# I am trying to access a class however i am not able to

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to access a class however I am not able to.

This class is a tag . Anything outside this tag is accessible. Can someone let me know why I am not able to access this class through JQuery?

Below is the code that I see when I inspect the page.

[HTML source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8b830.png)

Below is my JQuery code that i wrote:

```
    $ ('.btn-default').on('click',function(){
    alert("JQuery Running!");
});
```

Comment: please provide html as snippet.

Comment: @Rajkumar Somasundaram - I inserted the image of the HTML source code in the description above. Its a link to the image file

Comment: `jQuery` doesn't identify class if it is deep inside DOM tree.  Try this `$ ('[data-active-dom-element=""] .btn-default').on('click', function()});`

Comment: @phanther - I tried your example, however it did not work. Do i have to enter anything withing the ""? data-active-dom-element=""

Comment: @phanther where did you read this? What's the depth limit for classes?

Comment: still waiting for snippet, images dont help us debug

Comment: Please add a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/)

Comment: @Miro Did not read it anywhere. I have experienced such issue while using jquery.

Answer (score 4):

Your jQuery code looks pretty fine.My guess is that the your button containing the class btn-default is added dynamically after the DOM is loaded that's why you can't find it with your selector.Try using

```js
$ ('body').on('click','.btn-default',function(){
    alert("JQuery Running!");
});
```

suggesting not to bind your event on the body though, better use another parent that is a bit close to your button.

Comment: _"My guess is that the your button containing the class btn-default is added dynamically after the DOM is loaded"_ - And what makes you think so?

Comment: Just a random hypothesis. Ain't sure that's why I said I guess.

Comment: that was my guess also. Especially after seeing a `<ziggeo>` tag which is a video API service for recording video.

Comment: That's right.Looks like he's using a plugin which for most cases they add some html elements dynamically.

Comment: Welcome.I'm happy that it helped ya.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :
I have used `parents` method to identify the button.

```js
if ($( '.btn-default' ).parents('.main-level').length){
     $( '.btn-default').click(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
});
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class ="main-level">
   <div class ="level1">
     <div class = "level2">
        <other nested html>
                 <button class = "btn-default" id="1">

                Click here

                 </button>
        </other nested>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Without any code snippet, i have tried to answer his question and I hope this is the way how it gets selected properly. If you are downvoting it, you should explain the same, to prevent me to repeat the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:--

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  //if onhover get class or get id name
//$("p").hover(function(){
   //if onclick get class or get id name
$ ('p').on('click',function(){
    
        //if get onhover id
        alert("NOW GET ON HOVER ID NAME:--"+" "+this.id);
        
        //if get onhover class
        alert("NOW GET ON HOVER CLASS NAME:--"+" "+$(this).attr('class'));
        
        
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p class="getclass" id="get_class_id" >click</p>

 <!--   <p class="getclass" id="get_class_id" >on hover</p> -->

</body>
</html>
```